# Oracle ADF table refresh is working for a column, When full page refresh all the fields gets refreshed but displaying 1st tab instead of 5th tab

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using Oracle ADF 12c
I am have a table which is having input text and output text columns
By default, it is empty when i click the + icon the index, List Price, Selling Price and Line total fields will get updated and displayed in the table a first row.
We are providing few source code which is offering discounts to the user. When i user is placing the order using the offer source code the list price remains same but selling price will change based on discount percentage. This logic is working.
The problem is when i click on the button(Which is having the discount logic) all the fields get refreshed but not for selling price. When i print the selling price in backing bean class using the iterator there the value is printing correctly. But my table selling price remains the same.

Full page refresh is working perpectly but I am having the table in 5th tab. Using full page refresh its displaying 1st tab only and which is in another page(my 5th tab included as a region in another page). Is there any option to display 5th tab when full page refresh.

Any solution for this issue will be helpfull for me.
Thanks in advance

My table needs to refreshed with all the columns. Using execute query is giving more error for me so i am not looking for cache clear and execute query.
When full page refresh everything working fine but my table contains tab is not displaying when i click on reprice button

Comment: Can you show the code for the update of the table values, please? If you get an error reexecuting the query behind the table there is something fundamentally wrong.